# Slim.php `halt` method with code 304 does not print response body

Tags: php, slim

When I call `$app->halt(200, "Lorem ipsum");` or any other status code other than 304, it responds with the correct status code and prints out the body. But using the same code, just changing the 200 to 304 `$app->halt(304, "Lorem ipsum");`, the status code that is returned is 304 but the body is empty.

What could be the cause of this problem? how could I print out the response body with the response code 304?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a body with a 304. From the spec

> 10.3.5 304 Not Modified
>
> If the client has performed a conditional GET request and access is
>   allowed, but the document has not been modified, the server SHOULD
>   respond with this status code. The 304 response MUST NOT contain a
>   message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line
>   after the header fields.